# How to visualize current FPS when debugging a SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm coding a complex chart in SwiftUI that the user can scroll horizontally to see past data points.

The chart holds quite a few subviews inside so I would like to debug performance while scrolling.

Can anyone tell me how can I visualize current FPS (frames per second) when debugging my SwiftUI app. I've tried Instruments but can't seem to find anything related to displaying fps with SwiftUI.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Is this in Xcode simulator or on a physical test phone?

Comment: I would preferably debug in a real device but if that's not possible the simulator would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SwiftUI uses Core Animation for rendering, you can measure the FPS by profiling and using 'Core Animation FPS' instrument.

Other than that, you can check out [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-instruments-to-profile-your-swiftui-code-and-identify-slow-layouts) for a great tutorial about the SwiftUI specific Instrument, for identifiying slow layouts.

Make sure you are using a real device for that, because Core Animation FPS Instrument will not work with a simulator.

Comment: I did try before asking here in Stackoverflow the Core Animation FPS instrument while profiling my SwiftUI app but it didn't work. The issue was that I was trying it with the simulator which as you state is not supported. 

Tried it directly in a real device and it does work. Thanks for the tip!